# How to set the background color of a cell to a tinted black color

Tags: iphone, cell, tableview

I want to set the `color` of the `cell` to a transparent black. How can I do that?

I tried to set the `alpha` to .5 but it doesn't work.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.1 green: 0.1 blue: 0.1 alpha: 0.5];
```

Answer (score 3):

On the [`UITableViewCell` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there is the following note:

> Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting the background color of a cell via the `backgroundColor` property declared by `UIView`) you must do it in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method of the delegate and not in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  of the data source. Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded rectangle instead of the area outside of it.

So, put the code `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.1 green: 0.1 blue: 0.1 alpha: 0.5];` on the right place and it should work as you want.

Another option is to set a background view for you cell, with the selected color or gradient.

Answer (score 1):

set the cell background color in '`willDisplayCell`' delegate method of the tableView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
                                               forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.1 green: 0.1 blue: 0.1 alpha: 0.5]];
}
```

It will work now. Check It.

Answer (score 0):

`cell.background-color: transparent;`  with the page `background-color` set to black?

Comment: No, the tableView background will be an image, and the cells will be translucent black. Like a tinted window.